# Display inline values in other app's admin model

Tags: python, django, django-models, inline

I have been trying to figure it out but since I am not much experienced in this, I wanted to ask if there is a way to display the values from an inline at an other app's model.admin;

In my case:

**accounts\admin.py:**

```
@admin.register(models.Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'customer_subscription', 'company')
```

This is where I want to show inline values.

**core\admin.py:**

```
class ManageAddressInline(GenericStackedInline):
    model = AssignAddress

class CustomCustomerAdmin(CustomerAdmin):
    inlines = [ManageAddressInline]

admin.site.unregister(Customer)
admin.site.register(Customer, CustomCustomerAdmin)
```

**address_reports\model.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django_countries.fields import Country, CountryField

from accounts.models import Customer


class AssignAddressManager(models.Manager):
    def get_tags_for(self, obj_type, obj_id):
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj_type)

        return AssignAddress.objects \
            .select_related('manage-address') \
            .filter(
            content_type=content_type,
            object_id=obj_id
        )


class ManageAddress(models.Model):
    defined = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    apartment_or_suite = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    country = CountryField()


class AssignAddress(models.Model):
    objects = AssignAddressManager()
    apartment_or_suite = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    country = CountryField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

**address_reports\admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from address_reports.models import ManageAddress


@admin.register(ManageAddress)
class ManageAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['defined', 'apartment_or_suite', 'street', 'city', 'postal_code', 'country']
    list_display = ['defined', 'apartment_or_suite', 'street', 'city', 'postal_code', 'country']
```

Additionally, I would love some better approaches than this and would want to be able to manage address for a specific customer at the address_reports Tab.